# let films = await response.data.films.map(film =>

Tags: reactjs, express, npm, themoviedb-api

I'm getting this error massage when I run my server.js file.
Error Message:

> let films = await response.data.films.map(film =>{
>               ^^^^^
>       SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
>                   at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
>                   at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
>                   at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
>                   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
>                   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>                   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>                   at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>                   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>                   at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
>                   at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19

```
    app.get('/api/popular/movies', async (req, res, next)=> {

    axiosInstance.get(`filmsNowShowing/`).then(response=> {
        console.log(response.data.films)
        let films = await response.data.films.map(film =>{
            return {
                id:film.film_id,
                name:film.film_name,
                textLong:film.synopsis_long,
                picimage:film.images.poster
            }
        })
    res.status(200).json(films);
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed an `async` inside the `.then(response => { ... })`

```
    app.get('/api/popular/movies', async (req, res, next)=> {

    await axiosInstance.get(`filmsNowShowing/`).then(async response => {
        console.log(response.data.films)
        let films = await response.data.films.map(film =>{
            return {
                id:film.film_id,
                name:film.film_name,
                textLong:film.synopsis_long,
                picimage:film.images.poster
            }
        })
    res.status(200).json(films);
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
});
```